# react native android app crash on release mode

Tags: android, react-native

I can run the app on the emulator but can't generate a working APK for android.

I tried to run the app via Android studio and looking at the log cat i am getting

```
    Process: com.app.app, PID: 22827
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method "Lcom/facebook/jni/IteratorHelper;.hasNext()Z"
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.initializeBridge(Native Method)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl$Builder.build(Unknown Source)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.createReactContext(Unknown Source)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager$5.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
01-23 16:29:51.854 22827-22841/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-2
    Process: com.app.app, PID: 22827
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method "Lcom/facebook/jni/IteratorHelper;.hasNext()Z"
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.initializeBridge(Native Method)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl$Builder.build(Unknown Source)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.createReactContext(Unknown Source)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager$5.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
```

I have no clue where this is coming from
I am running react-native -v `0.55` with

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "27.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 27
        targetSdkVersion = 26
        supportLibVersion = "27.1.1"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

and following dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-restart')
    compile project(':react-native-sentry')
    compile project(':react-native-gesture-handler')
    compile project(':react-native-version-number')
    compile project(':react-native-image-picker')
    compile project(':react-native-splash-screen')
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    compile project(':react-native-wheel-picker')
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-base-support:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-webp:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:webpsupport:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:webpsupport:1.3.0'
}
```

**Update**

progaurd setting is applied to the project with the following settings

```
-keep class com.facebook.imagepipeline.animated.factory.AnimatedFactoryImpl { public AnimatedFactoryImpl(com.facebook.imagepipeline.bitmaps.PlatformBitmapFactory, com.facebook.imagepipeline.core.ExecutorSupplier); }

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-ignorewarnings

-keep class * {
    public private *;
}
```

Comment: are u using dexguard or proguard in your project ?

Comment: i have edite the question with the progaurd settings

Comment: -keepresourcefiles lib/*/libreact*.so
-keepresourcefiles lib/*/libmemchunk*.so

Try these configuration. As far i i got this u r application working fine in debug mode but not in signed build